# Parse a Java project by using JDT

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-jdt

I am writing a Swing Java application by using Java Development Tool (**JDT**) as follows.

**Input**: a Java project

**Output**: all name of elements in this project (*package*, *class*, *method*, *field*, etc.), etc.

Up to now, I have understand that how to parse a single *Java* file to collect pieces of information by using **JDT** to create corresponding **Abstract Syntax Tree** (AST). However, this approach will lead to lack of analysis information (Ex: Get all methods that call the same method).

How can I parse a project from an absolute path by applying **JDT** without parsing all single *.java* files independently?

Comment: It may seem that we cannot parse a project without running in plugin environment. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is we will parse each *.jav*a file independently. The obtained *AST* can be resolved binding. Method *Utils.getFile()* will get the content of the *.java* file and save in a String object.

```
    public parseJavaFile(String pathOfJavaFile, String[] sources, String[] classpath, String nameOfJavaFile)
        throws Exception {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);//choose source code analyzing strategy

    parser.setResolveBindings(true);// turn on binding strategy
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);// the source code is a file .java
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
    parser.setCompilerOptions(JavaCore.getOptions());

    parser.setUnitName(nameOfJavaFile);
    parser.setEnvironment(classpath, sources, new String[] { "UTF-8" }, true);
    parser.setSource(Utils.getFile(pathOfJavaFile).toCharArray());

    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    if (cu.getAST().hasBindingsRecovery()) {
        // Now binding is activated. Do something else
    }
}
```

Example of how to use the above code.

- *classpath* is corresponding to the absolute path of *rt.java* in *jre* folder.
- *sources* is a list of source code folders.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       String projectPath = "G:\\Dropbox\\Workspace\\Wave-CIA-rebuid-v2";
       String[] sources = { "G:\\Dropbox\\Workspace\\Wave-CIA-rebuid-v2\\src" };
       String[] classpath = { "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_40\\lib\\rt.jar" };
       String pathOfJavaFile = "G:\\Dropbox\\Workspace\\Wave-CIA-rebuid-v2\\src\\test.java";
       String nameOfJavaFile = "test.java";
       new parseJavaFile(pathOfJavaFile, sources, classpath, nameOfJavaFile);
  ```

  }

Answer (score -1):

You can use eclipse resourse.
Eclipse resourse will give you all project related information.

refer : http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_filesystem.htm